# TAI for MS Azure with Websphere Application Server v9 CWWSS8017E: Authentication Error

Tags: azure, websphere, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to configure SAML between MS Azure AD and a WebSphere v9 CF11 server that's sitting in AWS. But it is not recognizing the TAI set up

I've followed all the steps here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tsec_enable_saml_sp_sso.html and here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_configuresamlssopartners.html

I've installed the SAMLSA app in WebSphere, imported the metadata file provided by my Azure admin, and imported the certificate as well.  I've set up the ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor interceptor and put in (what I thought was) the right sso_1.sp.acsUrl and other settings for the server.

The SystemOut logs show that the ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor is loading:

SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor loaded successfully

but the version is null:

SECJ0122I: Trust Association Init Interceptor signature:

After setting it all up as above, when I go to the URL it just shows:

Error 403: AuthenticationFailed

And the log has errors about a missing cookie:

SECJ0126E: Trust Association failed during validation. The exception is com.ibm.websphere.security.WebTrustAssociationFailedException: CWWSS8017E: Authentication Error: Single-Sign-on cookie is not present or could not be verified. Please login to the SAML Identity Provider, and try again.

It's like it's never "intercepted" to be passed.  Just fails.  No network traffic goes to the AD server

When going to the URL it should redirect me to the MS Login and then back to the app, but it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be missing an sso_1.sp.login.error.page property definition. Without that property, the expectation is that the user will be going to the IdP to initiate the sign on; if you define the property and set its value to your IdP's login page, then the 403 you're getting (as a result of being unauthenticated) will end up redirecting you over to the IdP to initiate the sign on process from there.

More info here in the "bookmark style" description: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwbs_samlssosummary.html

Comment: Thanks, Jackson.  I added the error.page and set it to the same as SingleSignOnURL setting.  It does engage that error.page URL, but it's not passing any SAML parameters. It's expecting that I pass along the metadata information and return URL as parameters to that page... This is MS Azure, so if I just go to login.microsoftonline.com it will let me log in, but doesn't pass my back nor show me logged in if I return.  It's as if the TAI isn't passing the "I'm this app and please return me here after log in"

Comment: So if my application URL is https://www.myapp.com/app and the samlsps app is https://www.myapp.com/samlsps/apps I'd have the following settings:

sso_1.sp.acsUrl | https://www.myapp.com/samlsps/apps
sso_1.sp.idMap | idAssertion
sso_1.idp_1.EntityID | https://sts.windows.net/{appID from Azure}
sso_1.idp_1.SingleSignOnUrl | https://login.microsoftonline.com/{appID from Azure}/saml2
sso_1.idp_1.error.page | https://login.microsoftonline.com/{appID from Azure}/saml2

Comment: WAS supports IdP-initiated SSO (when you go to login.microsoft.com) SSO out of the box, but requires custom code to get true SP-initiated SSO working. Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cwbs_samlssoconcepts.html

Flow 1: You access login.microsoftonline.com, login, and I believe you're saying you get redirected to WAS but not to your application. If you define sso_1.sp.targetUrl and set the value to your application URL, I think that will resolve this problem.

Comment: Flow 2: Access the WAS app, and you get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com{appID from Azure}/saml2. I believe this must be an SP-initiated sign-on page, which is why the fact that there's no AuthnRequest sent from WAS is an issue. The easiest way to fix this would be to replace your sso_1.sp.login.error.page URL with an IdP-initiated login page URL... I am not sure if MS Azure has one of those though... if that's not an option, then the only way to fix this would be to implement an AuthnRequestProvider (see previous link) and plug that in as your login.error.page to enable SP-initiated.